# How to configure open fire to authenticate users from external database?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

This is the longest possible thread I have come across to fix a very simple problem to authenticate users from [external database in open fire](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/45325)

Proper fix is that do not change the properties in the `conf/openfire.xml`, Add the properties in the `ofProperty` table  mentioned [here](http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html)

```
e.g For Authentication Integration 

insert into ofProperty values('provider.auth.className', 'org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider');
insert into ofProperty values('jdbcAuthProvider.passwordSQL', 'SELECT password FROM user_account WHERE username=?');
insert into ofProperty values('jdbcAuthProvider.passwordType', 'plain');
```

stop the openfire and start the openfire.

**Note: All the settings in changed manually in the /conf/openfire.xml** will be lost when open fire starts.

**Question :**

- How do I login in to admin console after changing the properties ?
- Can openfire authenticate users from its own database and external
  database as well ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid inserting custom queries in the xml file or in the database. The best way is to add the data in the admin panel of openfire following the examples in the docs.

To allow your external users to log to the admin panel, you have to add their jabber id in admin.authorizedJIDs

Comment: I have another doubt, I have setup userAuthentication from remote database, and  I have few users in openfire database like 'admin' user, Can I login in with 'admin' user or this user should be present in remote database as well.

Comment: I have verified it works by adding properties in the database directly instead of adding in the admin console , as in general admin console can be opened only by accessing 127.0.0.1:9090/ url. Correct me if  I am wrong.

Comment: It may work after server restart, there are caching options for that.